# 6 javascript tasks assigned to me by my lecturer

Tags: javascript

I am a complete beginner to javascript. I am also new to this website. I am asking for help to complete an assignment. I have been trying for more than 4 hours by looking at lecture material and online for a solution. It is causing me a lot of unnecessary stress. Before javascript we only used CSS and Html. I was given 6 javascript tasks to manipulate the html file (taskc.html) already given to me.
The tasks are as follows

1. Make a statement to change contents of h1 from "Welcome" to "Text"
2. 2nd statement should make an new alert window when the page loads that delivers a message explaining what the page is about
3. 3rd statement should change the title to "text"
4. 4th statement should log the contents (innerHTML) of the first paragraph element in the console.
5. 5th statement should hide the contents of the second paragraph when the page loads
6. 6th statement should change the contents of the header to have a new colour of your choice

Here is that html.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Task C - The Document Object Mode</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1 id="header">Welcome</h1>
       <p id="first">This site uses JavaScript</p>
      <p id="second">Javascript is very useful</p>  
        </body>
         </html>
```

Because the actual coding im meant to add is meant to be in the .js file I was given. so I figured I had to link the js file in the html file so I added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="taskc.js"></script>
```

With that out of the way I went to the lecture notes and I thought I would simply need to modify some of the code given to me there like

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Hello World!';
```

When I put this code in brackets I got the error (document is not defined)
I modified it to match the requirements for task 1
here it is

```
document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = 'text';
```

I was confused because I didn't know what this error meant and of course Errors and how to fix them are never explained so I had to lookup how to resolve the error.
I found that to fix it I have to declare it as a variable so I ended up doing this.

```
var document = 'taskc.html';
```

When I did this for document, alert and console all the errors went away, but when I did a live preview only statement 1 was working
If anyone could help me fix this I would really appreciate because I don't understand enough javascript to be able to complete this in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: You don't need to define `document`, it's a predefined variable created by the browser.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I keep getting the error document is not defined, console is not defined, alert is not defined. They are all lower case too.

Comment: sounds like you are well on your way in solving the assignment ... keep chipping at it .... google `javascript onload`

Comment: You're running this in a browser, right? Not something like node.js.

Comment: yes running it in chrome.

Comment: are you running the code in the browser directly or are you using an on-line IDE?

Comment: You must be loading the code in an unusual way that's blocking access to global variables like `document`, `console`, and `alert`.

Comment: im just clicking the preview live button to what the code would look like on chrome. I just downloaded brackets 2 weeks ago if that matters at all

Comment: I click the live preview icon in brackets to load the code in chrome.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Brackets (this is the first time I've heard of it, I had to look it up), so I don't know why its live preview would work like this. It seems broken and perhaps you should find another way to test the code.

Answer (score -1):

So first: Please use Javascript functions to keep your code tidy and clean.

Example:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Task C - The Document Object Mode</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h1 id="header">Welcome</h1>
        <p id="first">This site uses JavaScript</p>
        <p id="second">Javascript is very useful</p>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="taskc.js">test();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
function test(){
    alert("This is a test!");
}
```

Always implement scripts that are document referenced at the bottom of your html.
If you use JQuery you can use following code to check document is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//foo bar
});
```

Comment: `document` is always defined, the location doesn't matter.

Comment: He says he's getting the error "alert is undefined". How does this solve that problem?

Comment: According to this statement he asks why document is not defined: "When I put this code in brackets I got the error (document is not defined) I modified it to match the requirements for task 1 here it is"

Comment: It sounds like there's a problem with the Live Preview feature of [Brackets](http://brackets.io/), not with the way he's written his code.